# How to resolve when Selenium partially crops emails when it scrapes?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have been using selenium to scrape emails however it partially cuts the first part of the email off... how should I go about fixing this? It seems no one else experiences this error -- is this a Colab thing or did I set the timeout too short? Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

For example:
Expected: example@gmail.com
Real: xample@gmail.com

```
from selenium import webdriver

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

def emailscrape(url):

  df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Email','URL source'])

  try: 
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(5)
    driver.get(url)

    ps = driver.page_source
    rgx_email = r'''(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])'''
    rgx_phone = r'''^\s*(?:\+?(\d{1,3}))?[-. (]*(\d{3})[-. )]*(\d{3})[-. ]*(\d{4})(?: *x(\d+))?\s*$'''
    email_list = []
    for i in re.finditer(rgx_email, ps):
      email_list.append(i.group())

    for j, e in enumerate(email_list):
      df = df.append({'Email': str(e), 'URL source': url},ignore_index=True)
    #  print(f'{j+1}: {e}')
    print('appended new group: ' + url)
    print(' Contact: '+ e)
  except: 
    print('Failed scraping of: '+ url)
  return df
```